# Ubuntu 16.04 gnome terminal double-click to highlight/copy

Tags: gnome

I am using the standard gnome terminal which came with my Ubuntu 16.04 install. When I select text in the terminal I can paste it with a middle-click of the mouse, so that is all fine. But what I want is to be able to double click text and have it selected/copied so I don't have to drag over an entire word to select it. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Double-click to select text is the default behaviour of gnome-terminal (v3.13.3 for reference). However, I came across this question because it stopped working for me. The solution, for me, was in the "Mouse & Touchpad" settings, I had to change the "Double-click" slider and set it about half-way between Slow and Fast.  I think gnome-terminal doesn't pick up my double-click when the setting is too far on the Fast side.

Comment: This didnt work for me, when I tried to increase it too far to the right it seemed to work once! I feel this tuning is difficult to do manually :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that setting the tap to click to true solved the issue.
Just execute the following commands:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true`

Comment: Tried this, didnt work for me

Comment: With the new ubuntu with gnome shell you can activate it right from settings -> Devices -> Mouse & Touchpad : Tap to click